# android < 2.3 and java.text.Normalizer

Tags: java, android, string, string-matching

What's the best alternative to to java.text.Normalizer in android versions previous than 2.3?
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Normalizer.html

I need to match Strings like

```
perché perchè perche
```

thanks

Nicola

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two solutions:

1.) Get the source for Normalizer from [here](http://docjar.net/html/api/sun/text/normalizer/NormalizerBase.java.html) and [here](http://docjar.net/html/api/sun/text/normalizer/NormalizerImpl.java.html). (it's a few thousand lines)

2.) Build a simple translation HashMap yourself. Maybe your will have just French users for some time? This is a suboptimal solution but practical until your app goes worldwide.

Comment: In the end I did solution 2. Might not be very elegant, but it works for me :)

Comment: I have tried to get the source for Normalizer. But on runtime I get: 1E/AndroidRuntime(29681): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime(29681): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not locate data