# How to match all accented forms of a particular character?

Tags: regex, unicode, pcre

I'd like to write a regular expression which will match all accented forms of a particular character in text encoded using some Unicode encoding, without explicitly listing out all such forms in a character class.

So, for example, if I'd like to match any accented version of `a`, `[aàáâãäå]` is insufficient, as it gets only the `a`'s which live in ISO-8859-1, and there may well be other accents which don't occur there. Something which would be acceptable is something like `\p{Base_Character: a}`, were there such a thing defined in Unicode. Does something which does this exist?

**Edit:** I can't ASCIIfy the string first---the string is in a database I don't have direct access to. I don't have code-level access to anything here, in fact. The only input I can give is a regex.

Answer (score 0):

No, no libraries exist that do anything other than list the related codes for accented versions.
Even within UTF-8, I do not see any discernable patterns among the codes.  Honestly though, making that list of other accented versions wouldn't take too long.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. 
A  workaround that could help, depending on your language/platform and needs, is to "[ascii-fy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523631/remove-accents-from-string)" your string before matching the `a`. For example, in Java:

```
    String s1 = "Hernán";
    String s2  = Normalizer.normalize(s1, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
            // s2: "Hernan"
    System.out.println(s2);
    System.out.println(s2.matches(".*a.*"));
```